# Identify Changes in Events

Tags: mysql

mySQL Database

I need some assistance/advice in figuring out the best approach and most effective way in identifying a change in an "event" field in a large data set.

I have some hardware that's logging temperature data. The temperature data is evaluated against some settings and categorised (1, 2 or 3). What I would like to do is to identify when a change of "event" / status happens and when it changes back, get the timestamp of this event.

I suspect the best and most obvious solution would be to simulate the windows LAG function. What makes it tricky is that the 3 option for this event code mean different things so I was thinking of using a sum of the event and lag(event) the result would identify the change from state 1 to state 3 for example. Also as the dataset is long (millions of rows) and the event will change state will change often I also only need the last change of state (the start of that period and end of period). There are also many meters reporting and each meter must be kept separate when evaluating change of state.

Interested if anyone has any advice or has had a similar query and how was it tackled. Open to any suggestions even a change in structure if it would make the queries quick and efficient with the desired result.

e.g data set

```
| date_time           | event_code | meter_id |
|---------------------|------------|----------|
| 2017-04-15 06:20:10 | 2          |1         |
| 2017-04-15 06:21:52 | 2          |2         |
| 2017-04-15 06:28:13 | 1          |2         |
| 2017-04-15 06:32:01 | 2          |1         |
| 2017-04-15 06:32:49 | 2          |2         |
| 2017-04-15 06:37:28 | 3          |1         |
| 2017-04-15 06:39:21 | 3          |1         |
| 2017-04-15 06:44:01 | 3          |1         |
| 2017-04-15 06:45:28 | 2          |1         |
| 2017-04-15 06:49:18 | 2          |2         |
```

Desired Result - assuming event_code 2 is the normal state

```
| date_time           | event_code | meter_id |
|---------------------|------------|----------|
| 2017-04-15 06:28:13 | 1          |2         | start and end event 1 meter 2
| 2017-04-15 06:32:49 | 2          |2         | start event 2 meter 2
| 2017-04-15 06:37:28 | 3          |1         | start event 3 meter 1
| 2017-04-15 06:44:01 | 3          |1         | end event 3 meter 1
| 2017-04-15 06:45:28 | 2          |1         | start and end event 2 meter 1
| 2017-04-15 06:49:18 | 2          |2         | end event 2 meter 2
```

EDIT DESIRED RESULT

```
| event_code | meter_id | last_evet_start     | last_evet_end       |
|------------|----------|---------------------|---------------------|
| 1          | 2        | 2017-04-15 06:45:28 | 2017-04-15 06:45:28 |
| 1          | 3        | 2017-04-15 06:37:28 | 2017-04-15 06:44:01 |
| 2          | 1        | 2017-04-15 06:28:13 | 2017-04-15 06:28:13 |
| 2          | 2        | 2017-04-15 06:32:49 | 2017-04-15 06:49:18 |
```

Comment: what is the desired result?

Comment: Have edited question with desired output/result

Comment: what happens with event_code = 2;?

Comment: agree, ill edit desired output again, it won't matter if I get the start and end timestamp for every evt_code change

Comment: Edited desired result with explanation, hopefully makes sense now?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the desired result, but you can get something similar on this way:

Rextester [here](http://rextester.com/RTAHH66574).

You can simulate a LAG function and set a new group every time event_code changes.

```
select date_time, event_code,
             if (@last_event = 0 or @last_event <> event_code, @grp := @grp + 1, @grp := @grp) reset_point,
             @last_event := event_code
      from (select @last_event := 0, @grp := 0) x,
           (select date_time, event_code
            from events
            where event_code <> 2
            order by date_time) y;

| date_time           | event_code | reset_point | @last_event := event_code |
|---------------------|------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| 15.04.2017 06:28:13 | 1          | 1           | 1                         |
| 15.04.2017 06:37:28 | 3          | 2           | 3                         |
| 15.04.2017 06:39:21 | 3          | 2           | 3                         |
| 15.04.2017 06:44:01 | 3          | 2           | 3                         |
```

The you can group by the new `grp` column and get max and min date_time.

```
select event_code, min(date_time) as start, max(date_time) as end
from (
      select date_time, event_code,
             if (@last_event = 0 or @last_event <> event_code, @grp := @grp + 1, @grp := @grp) reset_point,
             @last_event := event_code
      from (select @last_event := 0, @grp := 0) x,
           (select date_time, event_code
            from events
            where event_code <> 2
            order by date_time) y
     ) z
group by reset_point
;

| event_code | start               | end                 |
|------------|---------------------|---------------------|
| 1          | 15.04.2017 06:28:13 | 15.04.2017 06:28:13 |
| 3          | 15.04.2017 06:37:28 | 15.04.2017 06:44:01 |
```

Now you can unpivot it again, but let me know if this solution works for you.

Comment: Thanks, that could do it, ill include event_code 2 though but think this might do it

Comment: I'll simulate and run some test on the db in the morning

Comment: your approach works. I have used the LAG and incrementing idea but have included differentiating between meters as well as selecting the last event occurrence by using a max(reset_point) - this, however, has led to many selects in selects and I have had to build an intermediate table to simplify it all.
I have updated the original question with the final result required. Any ideas how I can get there in 1 go?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the desired result.